# Gamma ($\Gamma$) Convergence of Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Consider a set $X$, and consider a sequence of functionals on $X$, that is maps $F_n: X \to \mathbb{R}$. We say that $F_n$ "$\Gamma$" converges to $F$, if the limit satisfies:

1. $F(x) \leq \inf\{\liminf _{n \to \infty} F_n(x_n) : x_n \to x\}$

that is to say, for any sequence we $x_n \to x$ we choose, we have that $F(x) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty} F_n(x_n)  $. The second is the existence of a "$\Gamma$" realizing sequence, that is, there exists a sequence $x_n \to x$, that satisfies:

2. $\limsup_{n\to \infty} F_n(x_n) \leq  F(x)$

I have the following two questions about this limit.

First, is it accurate to replace condition $2$ with the condition that there exists a sequence $x_n$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x_n) \to F(x)$ ? (I.e., replacing the limsup with a bona-fide limit).

Second, is the characterization of $F(x)$ as :$$
F(x) = \min\{\liminf_{n \to \infty} F(x_n) : x_n \to x\}
$$
accurate? Is there an example of when this inf is not acheived? (i.e, we have no "realizing sequence"?

Answer (score 1):

If we take the realizing sequence according to (2) and put it into (1), then
$$
F(x) \le \liminf F_n(x_n) \le \limsup F_n(x_n)\le F(x),
$$
which shows $F(x) = \lim F_n(x_n)$ for this particular sequence.

So, yes, given condition (1), we can replace 'lim sup' by 'lim' in (2).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would you happen to have an example of functionals where there is no realizing sequence and thus no gamma convergence?